# how to make camel-example-cxf-proxy work in serviceMix 4.3.0

Tags: proxy, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I downloaded camel 2.6.0 and used example camel-example-cxf-proxy (under example folder) to deploy into serviceMix.
what i would like to do is  packaging it to become a jar file and then goto serviceMix karaf console to install this jar.

```
(install -s wrap:file:/c:/...jar)
```

But this example doesn't work in serviceMix 4.3.0.

Do you know what thing i have to modify to make it work within serviceMix 4.3.0
Do i have to install any other bundle into serviceMix?

Comment: Can you include any error message you get in your description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that you should make sure your maven project builds a bundle. I recently did a tutorial that shows how to run camel routes in OSGi:
http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/03/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+5+-+Running+Apache+Camel+integrations+in+OSGi

So basically you have to make sure that the camel features you need are installed. In your case this is probably camel-cxf and camel-http.

Then you need to change the pom to create a bundle. See the pom of the example:
https://github.com/cschneider/Karaf-Tutorial/blob/master/camel/jms2rest/pom.xml
You need to change the packaging to bundle and add the maven bundle plugin. For camel projects the default typically work very well.

Btw. you can also run camel on pure karaf when you follow the instructions in my tutorial. This has the advantage that you can almost always use the newest camel version while servicemix often comes with an older version.

Comment: Thanks Schneider. Your post does not directly solve my problem BUT i am really appreciate it. I went to your blog and saw a lot of useful information. Hopefully i can learn something new from your blog and solve my problem. Again, thanks very much